# geopy.exc.GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: geopy

Im trying to use geopy to get the lat/long but it throws a http 403 forbidden error.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
addr = '350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118'
location = geolocator.geocode(addr)
print location
```

It was all working fine for last few days.

```
    raise ERROR_CODE_MAP[code](message)
geopy.exc.GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Version of geopy 1.15.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably fixed the problem. According to this documentation https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#nominatim
you need to specify user-agent for each app that is using Nominatim

```
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="name_of_your_app")
```

Answer (score 7):

"GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges" error - try to use 'Photon' instead of 'Nominatim'

```
from geopy.geocoders import Photon
geolocator = Photon(user_agent="measurements")
```