# geopy.exc.GeocoderAuthenticationFailure: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: python, geopy, geonames

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude of a location using GeoPy with Python. I tried implementing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686001/python-module-for-getting-latitude-and-longitude-from-the-name-of-a-us-city#13686031), as below:

```py
from geopy.geocoders import GeoNames
gn = GeoNames(username='[my username]')
gn.geocode("Cleveland, OH 44106")
```

But I get this error:

> geopy.exc.GeocoderAuthenticationFailure: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

I am registered on http://www.geonames.org, and I also tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503389/geopy-exc-geocoderinsufficientprivileges-http-error-403-forbidden) but I get the same error, unless the `user_agent` has to be specified somewhere with http://www.geonames.org?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I had to enable *Free Web Services* at https://www.geonames.org/manageaccount when logged into my account, it works as expected now.